Regex that match exactly half of an even sized doubled string
I have variable even sized duplicated strings like:
BananaBanana
DeltaDelta
Avocado 123Avocado 123

I would like to get rid of the first or last half of it.
I thought of something like a regex that match half of a string ignoring the content, or a regex that match a string that is followed by a string equal to itself, like a look ahead that references something already matched. Don't know if it's possible.
I tried this: ^(.+)(?=\1)$

This worked: ^(.+)\1$ replacing it by \1
Still don't get why ^(.+)(?=\1)$ doesn't work.
UPDATE
As the original question is to match half the string, the correct solution is the one pointed by @Chrᴉz remembers Monica:
^(.+)(?=\1)

^(.+)(?=\1)$ does not work because the positive lookahead is no part of the match. So there's still a "Banana" missing to match till the end of the string. ^(.+)(?=\1) or ^(.+)(?=\1).*$would work.

https://regex101.com/r/2ZaWOa/1 or https://regex101.com/r/SiY6Jp/1 as @Chriz said

The $ assertion should not be made outside the look-ahead assertion, because there the "cursor" is still half-way the input string (assuming it is valid). You need to put that $ assertion inside the look-ahead assertion:
^(.+)(?=\1$)

